# Error with the date: argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

Tags: python, django, datetime

**polls/models.py:**

```
class Message(models.Model):
    auteur = models.ForeignKey(Personne)
    contenu = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now(), blank=True, verbose_name="Date de publication")
```

**views.py:**

```
def welcome(request):
    logged_user = get_logged_user_from_request(request)
    if not logged_user is None:
        if 'newMessage' in request.GET and request.GET['newMessage'] != '':
            newMessage = Message(auteur=logged_user, contenu=request.GET['newMessage'], pub_date =  datetime.now())
            newMessage.save()
        friendMessages = Message.objects.filter(auteur__amis=logged_user).order_by('-pub_date')
        return render_to_response('polls/home.html', {'logged_user': logged_user, 'friendMessages': friendMessages})
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/login')
```

When I run:

```
python manage.py migrate
```

I get this traceback:

> TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'datetime.datetime'

I don't now why I have this error.

Comment: Did you try with `auto_add_now` ? : `pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_add_now=True, blank=True, verbose_name="Date de publication")`

Comment: i have the same error with auto_add_now=True

Comment: can you show in code how you import datetime ? Other question, did you change something on the model, what is the output of makemigrations ?

Comment: from datetime import datetime

Comment: no i have obtain this error when i have add the dateFields

Comment: Can you add your migration file that causing the issue  ?

Comment: i can't add my full traceback i have this message : It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details.

Comment: Remove the view code, it seems to be irrelevant to your problem.

Comment: When you added dateFields did you run makemigrations then run migrate?

Comment: unrelated: do  not use `datetime.now()` in your server (the local timezone that your server happens to use is irrelevant for your users and the naive local time may be ambiguous). Use `django.utils.timezone.now` instead  ([add `USE_TZ = True` to enable timezone-aware datetime objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/i18n/timezones/)). Make sure you understand the difference between `f` (the function object itself -- you can pass it as an argument in Python too) and `f()` (the function call that returns specific result) in Python.

Answer (score 0):

`default=datetime.now()` is the part that fails, but even if you fix it, it is a bad idea. It will set your default to whatever the date is when you app starts, since datetime.now() will only be evaluated once. What you probably want is `auto_add_now=True` as mentioned in the comments.